# How to route guard against non existent url paths?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to redirect the user to a 404 page I've created in the event they try to access a page that doesn't exist (Ex. /blogs/nonexistent-title). The problem is that I'm making an http get request to a database and checking if the returned item is null. if it is is null, i will send the user to the 404 page. However angular http returns an observable that is never null, regardless of whether the database returns null.

HTTP

```
getSingleBlogArticle(title:String):Observable<BlogEntryModel>   {
    return this.http.get(this.getBlogArticleUrl+"/"+title,httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('Get form details'))
    );
  }
```

Route Guard

```
  constructor(private resolverService: ResolveService, private router: Router,private websiteBackendService :WebsiteBackendService) { 

  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    let item = this.websiteBackendService.getSingleBlogArticle(route.params['id']);
       let containsRoute = !!this.websiteBackendService.getSingleBlogArticle(route.params['id']);
       console.log(item);
       if(!containsRoute) {
         this.router.navigate(['/404']);
       }

    return containsRoute;
  }
```

Routing

```
{path:'blog/:id',component: FullBlogEntryComponent,canActivate:[RouteActivatorService]},
```

Comment: getSingleBlogArticle returns Observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are currently treating `getSingleBlogArticle` as if it's a synchronous responses, rather than an RxJS `Observable<any>`. [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) that you are implementing in this guard, expects the following return types:

```
Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
```

Try the following using pipeable operators [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) and [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) to transform the response to a boolean via `!!` then execute a navigate/redirect if the value is falsy:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...    

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.websiteBackendService.getSingleBlogArticle(route.params['id']).pipe(
    map(response => !!response),
    tap(containsRoute => {
      if (!containsRoute) {
        this.router.navigate(['/404']);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

I'd highly recommend to review the Angular documentation on [Observables]. Also the section on [Route Guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) extensively references using Observables with guards as well as route data resolvers.

Hopefully that helps!